# Page is not being loaded in GWT

Tags: gwt

I am using activities and places to develop my application. When I click on the link on the left, my page is loaded, and I put the values in the fields. After I put the values, I send a RPC to the server, and get response back. This is also shown. Now the problem is that even if I click on the link on the left, I am getting the result page again. I am not getting the input page.

**Impl code**

```java
@UiHandler("entInvoiceCompare")
void onClickSubmit(ClickEvent e) {  
    GWT.log("Going to enterprise compare place");
    //listener.goTo(new EnterpriseInvoiceCompareViewPlace());
    NewEBRM.getClientFactory().getPlaceController().goTo(new EnterpriseInvoiceCompareViewPlace());
}
```

**Place**

```java
public class EnterpriseInvoiceCompareViewPlace extends Place{

    public EnterpriseInvoiceCompareViewPlace() {
        GWT.log("EnterpriseInvoiceCompareViewPlace: constructor");
    }


    public static class Tokenizer implements PlaceTokenizer<EnterpriseInvoiceCompareViewPlace> {

        @Override
        public String getToken(EnterpriseInvoiceCompareViewPlace place {               
            GWT.log("EnterpriseInvoiceCompareViewPlace: getToken: call");
            return "EntInvoiceCompare";
        }

        @Override
        public EnterpriseInvoiceCompareViewPlace getPlace(String token) {   
            GWT.log("EnterpriseInvoiceCompareViewPlace: getPlace: call");
            return new EnterpriseInvoiceCompareViewPlace();
        }

    }

}
```

**Activity**

```java
@Override
public void start(AcceptsOneWidget containerWidget, EventBus eventBus) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    GWT.log("EnterpriseInvoiceCompareActivity: start: starting activity");
    EnterpriseInvoiceCompareView entInvoiceCompareView = clientFactory.getEnterpriseInvoiceCompareView();
    entInvoiceCompareView.setPresenter(this);
    containerWidget.setWidget(entInvoiceCompareView.asWidget());
    GWT.log("EnterpriseInvoiceCompareActivity: start: ending activity");
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: And how can anyone help you if we don't see your code?

Comment: What about the link? Did you set a ClickHandler on it?

Comment: Yes this is on the link only: The problem is that I am not getting the input page again, after I submit the request first time
@UiHandler("entInvoiceCompare")
void onClickSubmit(ClickEvent e)
{   
    GWT.log("Going to enterprise compare place");
    //listener.goTo(new EnterpriseInvoiceCompareViewPlace());
    NewEBRM.getClientFactory().getPlaceController().goTo(new EnterpriseInvoiceCompareViewPlace());
}

Comment: Do you get the log message when you click on this link? If you do, there may be a problem in your ActivityMapper or ClientFactoryImpl class.